# Google Static Maps API: double-digit labels and anchors

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

A couple of questions about using Google's static maps,(http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/).

Can't seem to find an answer (maybe due to the impossibleness of what I need)

1. Is there no way to display markers with double-digit labels such as '11', '12', etc. ?
   I have more than 10 markers and I label them by simple numbers - Am I really restricted to using only 0...9 ? (the uppercase letter are of no use to me)
2. What would be the way to make the markers anchors? Do I need to use the Google maps javascript library ?

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static Maps API serves an image only, so making the markers (on the served image) anchor tags is not really possible.

I guess you could sort of do it through an HTML image map, but trying to figure out how to make that work reliably is all but certainly vastly more difficult than just using Google Maps API v3 instead of the Static Maps API.

Google Maps API v3 may have limitations too, depending on your use case, but it will certainly get you a lot closer a lot faster.

Answer (score 2):

Your only option might be to color code the numbers, 1-9 red, 1-9, blue and so on.  If you are using Static maps as a  backup, then outputting a corresponding explanation could be possible too. Still, hackish isn't it? Pity you cant do numbers then letters... thatd give you 36 at least.

Answer (score 2):

I tried it with chars like "a" to "z", but without a reason :( but i found a cool notice in the google docs: Google allows more than 2000 markers for each "static map".